# The JSON value could not be converted to System.DateTime

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core-webapi, json-deserialization

I have an **Employee** table

```
public class Employee
{
   [Key]
   public long ID { get; set; }
   public DateTime EmpDate { get; set; }
   public string FirstName { get; set; }
   public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

I have created web API to post the employee data:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult<Employee>> PostLead(Employee employee)
{
      //Code to post
}
```

This is my JSON body

```
{
    "firstname":"xyz",
    "lastname":"abc",
    "EmpDate":"2019-01-06 17:16:40"
}
```

I am getting error as `The JSON value could not be converted to System.DateTime.` But when I pass **EmpDate** value as `2019-01-06`, I am not getting an error.

Comment: Can't you change your EmpData property to string?

Comment: Use ISO 8601 format: "2019-01-06T17:16:40.000"

Comment: @LinkedListT Yes, I can. However, there are a lot of other functionalities that depend on DateTime EmpDate.

Comment: Just an aside, but, assuming your JSON comes from JavaScript use `Date.toISOString` on the JS side; ASP.NET handles ISO strings fine.

Comment: @user1538301, I am calling this API from PHP.

Comment: @Adi not a PHP buff but find a way to convert it into an ISO string on the PHP side before sending it to your ASP.NET server

Comment: Instead of "DateTime" class, try using "DateTimeOffset" struct. This works for most JSON APIs I call.

Comment: Hello all, ISO 8601 is working for me in Postman. I will update now in code. Thank you all.

Comment: Aside, @Adi, should that be `public class Employee`? You're binding to an `Employee` object, but your class name is `Lead`. (I assume this is just a typo, but it may be worth editing to avoid confusion.)

Comment: The date-time value in the json is not wrong. It should be considered as a "custom formatting". Despite ISO 8601 is working, it does not mean that everyone has to use it. String data parsing is a concern of business logic and if I need to use "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss" formatting then I need to say the parser to use that formatting. Think about this way. You're doing a 3rd party integration and they're not changing their formatting, say they're a payment gateway provider and widely used world-wide.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

your date value in your JSON isn't correct. should be

```
2019-01-06T17:16:40
```

Most parsers use [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

Comment: Actually the date-time value in the json is not wrong. It should be considered as a "custom formatting". Despite of most parsers using ISO 8601 by default, it does not mean that you/him/me have to use it. String data parsing is a concern of business logic and if I need to use "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss" formatting then I need to say the parser to use that formatting. Think about this way. You're doing a 3rd party integration and they're not changing their formatting, say they're a payment gateway provider and widely used world-wide.

Comment: Also use `new Date(stringValue).toISOString()`

Comment: You might also want to specify a timezone, e.g `2019-01-06T17:16:40Z` (Z at the end means it's UTC)