# How to specify date format in RestSharp request

Tags: restsharp

I have this piece of code:

```
            var client = new RestClient(fullUri);
            var request = new RestRequest(GetMethod(method));
            client.UseSerializer(
                () => new RestSharp.Serialization.Json.JsonSerializer { DateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" }
            );
            request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
            request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            if (body != null)
                request.AddJsonBody(body);
            var response = client.Execute(request);
            if (response.ErrorException != null)
                throw response.ErrorException;
            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResponseData>(response.Content);
```

Note the

```
        client.UseSerializer(
            () => new RestSharp.Serialization.Json.JsonSerializer { DateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" }
        );
```

I have added that code because I need the date format to be `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` instead of `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.zzzzz` (the default)

`RestRequest.DateFormat` is obsolete.

When the calling is made, I saw that a date is passed using the default format, instead of the custom one.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 3):

I will suggest rewrite your code. Here my comments and example:

1. First, if you try to use this format for *DateTime* `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` you will get a validation error from web API service when you try to send a request.

```
{
   "type":"https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
   "title":"One or more validation errors occurred.",
   "status":400,
   "traceId":"00-a0c978c054625441b8ddf4c552b0f34c-314723fc8ce3ac4e-00",
   "errors":{
      "$.DateTime":[
         "The JSON value could not be converted to System.DateTime. Path: $.DateTime | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 33."
      ]
   }
}
```

This means - you use incorrect format for DateTime. You should use this format `"yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss"`. Read more in question [The JSON value could not be converted to System.DateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59866943/the-json-value-could-not-be-converted-to-system-datetime).
Don't forget add `T` because parsers use [ISO_8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)

2. Second, I would highly recommend *do not use* `JsonSerializer` from `RestSharp`, because I faced different problems with it. I highly recommend to use `System.Text.Json` from Microsoft or `Newtonsoft.Json`. Read more about [System.Text.Json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to?pivots=dotnet-5-0) or [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json).
3. Third, let's code! My example of web api service.

```
        [HttpGet]
        public string Test()
        {
            var client = new RestClient("your url");
            var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);

            var body = new SimpleRequestBody
            {
                DateTime = DateTime.Now
            };
            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(body,
                new JsonSerializerSettings()
                {
                    DateFormatString = "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss"
                });

            request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
            request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            if (body != null)
                request.AddParameter("application/json", json, null, ParameterType.RequestBody);

            var response = client.Execute(request);
            // response.ErrorException -> Could not handle bad request
            // Better to user IsSuccessful property
            if (!response.IsSuccessful)
                throw new Exception(response.Content);

            return response.Content;
        }
        public class SimpleRequestBody
        {
            public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
        }
```

Example of client web api code:

```
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Post([FromBody] SimpleResponse response)
        {
            var result = $"OK result from another web api. DateTime {response.DateTime}";
            return Ok(result);
        }
        public class SimpleResponse
        {
            public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

4. Results

[image: Json value]

[image: Api response]