# The JSON value could not be converted to System.DateTime is my error on console

Tags: json, reactjs, axios

The error is bad request 400, data is this:  `data {\"id\":2,\"name\":\"Tuesday\",\"from\":\"21:16:09\",\"to\":\"23:16:06\"}"`
I have issues converting dateTime to time in reactjs with axios.
I have no issues on Postman, but with axios i can't convert:
Here is the pre-request script on Postman:

```
var moment = require("moment");

pm.environment.set('from',moment().add(14, 'hours').toISOString());
pm.environment.set('to',moment().add(30, 'hours').toISOString());
```

Here is the form in ReactJs:

```
<Form onSubmit={handleSubmit} autoComplete='off'>
                <Form.Input placeholder='Day' value={workinghour.name} name='name' onChange={handleInputChange}/>
                <Form.Input type='time' step='2' placeholder='From' value={workinghour.from} name='from' onChange={handleInputChange}/>
                <Form.Input type='time' step='2' placeholder='To' value={workinghour.to} name='to' onChange={handleInputChange}/>
```

And i use this to split the datetime and to get just time:

```
useEffect(() => {
        agent.WorkingHours.list().then(response => {
            let workinghours = [];
            response.forEach(workinghour => {
                workinghour.from = workinghour.from.split('T')[1]
                workinghour.from = workinghour.from.split('.')[0];
                workinghour.to = workinghour.to.split('T')[1];
                workinghour.to = workinghour.to.split('.')[0];
                workinghours.push(workinghour);
            })
            setWorkingHours(workinghours);
        })
    }, [])
```

Comment: There is no `time` key in moment.js `.add()`.... Is that a typo? Maybe it should be `days`? [moment.js add() documentation](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/add/)

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette i changed it into hour, it still works on postman, but with axios it doesnt convert to datetime

Comment: Put a `console.log('workinghour.from =', workinghour.from);` and the same for the `to` in your `handleSubmit()` to show exactly what's getting sent to the server. In your Postman script you are explicitly converting to ISO format before sending; whatever is getting sent by axios is probably not ISO format or anything like it.

Comment: @NealBurns workinghour.from = 21:16:09
 workinghour.to = 23:16:06 this is showing in console, also i wrote what data shows in console, data: "{\"id\":2,\"name\":\"Tuesday\",\"from\":\"21:16:09\",\"to\":\"23:16:06\"}"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took this from your Postman script and ran it in the browser console:

```
> moment().add(30, 'hours').toISOString()
> "2021-07-12T07:40:15.936Z"
```

The format you are sending via axios is this: "21:16:09", which is missing the date, fractional seconds, time zone suffix ("Z" for UTC), and the letter "T" between the date and time.

"The JSON value could not be converted to System.DateTime" <-- Is this coming from ASP.NET? If that's the case, ASP.NET is trying to make a `DateTime`, which is both a date and a time.

Take a look at [previous discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59866943/the-json-value-could-not-be-converted-to-system-datetime) on this topic and you can probably take it from here. If you get stuck, leave a comment and I'll write back.

Comment: can i send the time like that, just hour, minutes and seconds. I don't need a date, but i was forced to declare it as a DateTime in the .cs file.

Comment: Can't you change it from DateTime to string?